# job in a multijob phase stuck at pending, so long as upstream project Multijob1 is running

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

In Jenkins 2.7.2, trying to run a multijob (Multijob1) with some phases, the first phase runs Job_A with many predefined parameters.

When runnig Multijob1:

in the console output of Multijob1 I get:

"Started building job Job_A "

and in the build history for Job_A I get:

"pending - upstream project Multijob1 is already building"

**When I abort Multijob1, Job_A starts running nicely, with all the predefined params that were specified for it in the Multijob1 phase.**

It's as if the Job_A is waiting for the upstream job that initiates it to finish, before running. Of course, the upstream job relies on Job_A which it blocks, to run and finish before it can run and finish! La la loop!

What's stopping my stupid Job_A from running?

Comment: For he/she who upped this tumbleweed question with a +1 (cheers!), in assuming you've run into the same loopsiloop - Jenkins pipeline will sort you out. Feel free to contact me if you need help.